# get access to cordova on remote site

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-fcm

I developed a progressive webapp and would like to use cordova and a cordova FCM plugin to display notifications on iOS, how can I load my site remote in cordova and still get access to cordova and cordova plugins?

Comment: If i understand your question correctly, I do not think what you want is possible, most of the cordova api's use plugins in the backend to call the native function.  These plugins are embedded in the compiled application

Answer (score 0):

[This is how your server should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buqt0.png)
I'm not sure if this answer to your ask but imho you should change the content of the config.xml from "index.html" to "link/to/your/remote/server/bonzo/index.html"

Comment: I tried this, but once my site is loaded I don't get access to cordova and can't use any cordova plugins.

Comment: is cordova.js on your server? You should have your plugin installed in the "empty app" and the cordova.js on your server